# How to use babel-node with pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2, babel-node, babel-cli

I want to manage my node process with pm2 package.
If I don't have any es6 syntax in my code so I don't need to add babel-node, and without any es6 syntax code is am able to run my code with pm2 with this line of code

```
pm2 start server.js
```

But as soon as I add any line of code of es6 syntax like this

```
import express from 'express';
```

I get the error of unexpected token import.

As you know to solve this issue we have to add babel-node package.

But when I use this line of command to compile my code

```
pm2 start server.js --interpreter babel-node
```

I get this error

```
Error: spawn babel-node ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

The strange thing about this is that if I don't use pm2 and run the code with this line of code

```
babel-node server.js
```

Every thing is OK.

Answer (score 14):

I've only just started using pm2 and I found [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/pm2-use-npm-to-start-your-app) helped.

You have your npm script to run es6 js, something like

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "server": "babel-node ./src/server.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

Then to run that with pm2 you use `pm2 start npm -- run server`
Make sure you have `babel-cli` installed globally.

Answer (score 13):

Install babel-cli in your project with `yarn add babel-cli` and then you can run
`pm2 start ./server.js --interpreter ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js`

With "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0" the path is `./node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js`

Comment: Worked elementaryOS 5.0

Comment: With `"@babel/cli": "^7.0.0"` the path is `./node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js`

Answer (score 4):

**use this command to run a project**

```
pm2 start --interpreter babel-node server.js
```

Answer (score 1):

pm2 start --interpreter babel-node server.js

**use this command to run a project on to the server**

Answer (score 0):

check pm2 log files to trace the error.
the location of log files is at /root/.pm2/

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue in my Node.js project that I use babel.

First you must have

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
   "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
   "eslint": "^7.9.0"
}
```

in your package.json file.

And then you can use

```
pm2 start bin/www --interpreter node_modules/@babel/node/bin/babel-node.js
```

command on your terminal. That's it, your project will stand up with babel configurations. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was reading this I found something related to this point "Error: spawn babel-node ENOENT" I think the problem isn't with pm2, It is related to the path, I mean the problem is with your environment!

**well, how to fix it!**

> first, let me be really clear about this, I have been working with pm2
> for about 4 years and it is the best in my opinion, but in windows
> environment it is creasy! soo my solution to not lose time, is nodemon
> for windows, if you are using Linux "WALA nop problems",

my way!
in my server(Linux or Ubuntu) for production or testing, I always use pm2 and as a dependence, I install nodemon just in case my team wants to use it on windows!

[image: example babel pm2 nodemon]

**red lines are for Linux and green for Windows **

another way to use is to install ubuntu on windows from WINDOWS STORE

[image]

> This allows you to run a Linux terminal on windows but you have to
> install nodejs on your local instance!

this example was for a friend how was losing time loving pm2, he is using this way and he is happyYYYYY